Combining Data from Multiple Participants for Statistical Analysis of a Facial Expression Memory Task

Context of the Query: I am working on a project involving a memory task for facial expressions, consisting of two phases:

Encoding Phase: In this phase, participants are exposed to 8 virtual characters, each displaying one of four distinct facial expressions (pain, anger, sadness, neutral) across 8 trials.
Recall Phase: This phase consists of 24 trials (in a random order), divided into three categories:

8 "Old identity, old expression" Trials: Participants must recognize characters with the same facial expressions as those shown during the Encoding Phase. The task is to confirm if they have seen the exact character-expression combination previously.
8 "Old identity, new expression" Trials: Here, the characters are the same as those seen in the Encoding Phase, but they display different facial expressions. Participants need to identify that they have seen the character before, albeit with a different expression.
8 "New identity" Trials: These trials feature entirely new characters that were not presented in the Encoding Phase. Participants must identify that they have not seen these characters before.


The 8 trials of each condition is distributed evenly among four facial expressions (pain, anger, sadness, and neutral) with each expression appearing twice. In all cases, participants are required to specify whether they have seen the exact character-expression combination, only the character (with a different expression), or if they haven’t seen the character at all.

Statistical Challenge:
The main challenge arises from the limited number of trials per expression per participant, which restricts the use of traditional statistical methods like signal detection theory.
For instance, the calculation of the hit rate for 'pain' expression relies on only two trials. This occurs because, during the recall phase, in all the 'old' trials, only two instances feature the expression of 'pain' and are relevant for calculating its hit rate (8 characters/4 expressions = 2 occurrences each). The resultant hit rates are constrained to the values of 0%, 50%, or 100%. Such a constrained range of values does not lend itself well to typical statistical analyses like ANOVA (to compare memorization of all four facial expressions) due to non-normal distribution of the data.
My question is: Are there any statistical techniques that allow for the combination of data across multiple participants to form "macro-participants" for the calculation of statistics such as hit rate or accuracy? The idea would be to randomly group data from 3 or 4 participants to compute these statistics and then perform hypothesis testing on them.
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Hit rate =  the proportion of "old" or previously seen items that are correctly identified as 'old' by the participants = Number of hits / Total number of 'old' items

A few things aren't clear to me. 1) Do you have a succinct statement of the hypotheses or objectives of your study? 2) As stated, the design implies that each subject will be exposed to one encoding phase and three recall phases. Is this correct?

Hello, thanks for your comment ! 1) The goals of our study are: A) To compare the memory recall of facial expressions of pain with other facial expressions (anger, sadness, neutral); and B) To investigate whether there are differences in the memorization of the identity (i.e., the specific character) versus the facial expression. 2) Regarding your second question, each subject actually undergoes one encoding phase composed of 8 trials and a single recall phase, which consists of 24 trials that are split into three conditions (8 trials each).

Ok...sounds like lots of potential confounding of facial groups plus subject fatigue. A few really basic, psychometric comments. You've established clear boundaries between facial classes, i.e., their construct validity, yes? Randomized exposure within each phase seems critically important. Try modeling the data as a fixed effects pooled time series study with exposure as time and facial types as pooled FEs --the ultimate macro participant as a baseline. Then expand to a random effects of participant model. Evaluate how things change--eg, which subjects explain the most variance, etc
